# Make feature in WIX unavailable instead of hiding it

Tags: wix

I have a condition, depending on directory search, it will disable a feature to prevent overwriting of files. But what I actually need is to set the feature in the selection tree to "Entire feature will be unvailable" instead of hiding the entire feature.

Any ideas how to do it?

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature2" Title="lorem ipsum" Description="dolor sit amet" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Absent="allow">
      <Condition Level="0">
        <![CDATA[CHECKCFGDATA<>"NOTEXIST"]]>
      </Condition>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Component1" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Component2" />
    </Feature>
```

Comment: What files are overwritten? Can you remove them from your new setup and install them as read-only templates somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't have this feature natively.  You could set the level to greater then the INSTALLLEVEL property (default 100) and it wouldn't be installed but it would only say will not be installed.  The user could still select it to be installed unless you implemented some additional logic to prevent transition to the next screen if your property says it shouldn't be installed and they are trying to install it.

Any attempt to get a UX more like what you ask would require writing a custom UI handler.